# Controls of appbar in windows 8

Tags: windows-8

I am doing a windows 8 app project and I want to place an app bar  for my app and i want to place buttons like zoom in and zoom out in my app bar how should code for those buttons??

Comment: Are you using XAML or HTML? A bit different depending on which, but start by looking at the [XAML AppBar Control Sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/XAML-AppBar-control-sample-2aa1cbb4) or the [HTML AppBar Control Sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/App-bar-sample-a57eeae9)

Comment: xmal C# I did nt get code for zoom in and zoom out there sir

Comment: What are you asking? An appbar sample of an zoom in/out sample? When you say zoom in/out are you asking about Semantic Zoom ? You should give to us more information.

Comment: As David points out, there's also a question of semantic vs. optical zoom - see [Guidelines for Optical Zoom and Resizing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj883704.aspx) for more.  Either case is pretty well described, but try the [XAML scrolling, panning, and zooming sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/xaml-scrollviewer-pan-and-949d29e9), then combine the AppBar samples above to help you with creatting command buttons.  If you run into something, post details so we can help you a bit more specificaly.